# Would it be possible to leverage Meteor's packaging system without all of the webapp stuff?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to create a node shell script that leverages Meteor's packaging system. Is it possible to do this without having to run "meteor" and without starting a server?

A simple example:

```
// A JS file in the root of a meteor app:

#!/usr/bin/env node
// this would be from an exported package variable
console.log("Exported package var: ", ExportedVarFromAPackage)
```

Comment: What's your goal? To have a portable shell script written in javascript?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone Exactly. But I'd also like for it's functionality to be able to be extended with Meteor packages.

Comment: Is there something in Meteor's packages that's not in npm?

Comment: Using meteor packages would allow Meteor developers to easily extend the shell script. Since they would already likely be familiar with the process of building a meteor package. So it's more of a convenience thing.